In what sense is a change of boundary conditions a finite rank perturbation?
Duplicate of How is changing the boundary conditions a finite rank perturbation?, but this was never answered.
In the paper "Operators with Singular Continuous Spectrum V: Sparse Potentials" by Simon and Stolz, it is said at the bottom of page 5 that:

Whole-line problems differ from the direct sum of two half-line problems only by adding boundary conditions at 0, a finite rank perturbation

Could someone make this explicit or give a reference that does so? It's unclear to me what perturbation is being done and how this perturbation will be finite rank.
